# Why does String::from(*d) give a different result from *d.to_string() on a &&str?

Tags: rust

I am a bit puzzled by why dereferencing a `&&str` doesn't seem to work in the second case:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let days = vec!["mon", "tue", "wed"];
    let mut hs: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();

    for d in &days {
        // works
        hs.insert(String::from(*d));

        // doesn't
        hs.insert(*d.to_string());
    }
    println!("{:#?}", hs);
}
```

`str` does implement a `ToString` trait, but it still gives me the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:19
   |
12 |         hs.insert(*d.to_string());
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found str
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `str`
```

What syntax am I getting wrong here?

[Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b1378e98b62e4e6424dbd6d91a23f39d&version=stable)

Comment: Note that function call has higher precedence than deref; `*d.to_string()` applies the dereference to the result of the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_string` is called to `d` before it's deref'd, so you will deref the `String`, which results in `str`.

Change it to

```
hs.insert(d.to_string());
```

This works because `d` is automatically deref'd to `str`, which will be converted into `String` afterwards. This is called [*Deref coercions*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html).

> If you have a type `U`, and it implements `Deref<Target=T>`, values of `&U` will automatically coerce to a `&T`
>
> ...
>
> Deref will also kick in when calling a method

This is [exactly the case here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref): `impl Deref<Target = str> for String`. See [here for an example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html#deref-and-method-calls):

> A value of type `&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&Foo` can still have methods defined on `Foo` called, because the compiler will insert as many `*` operations as necessary to get it right. And since it’s inserting `*s`, that uses `Deref`.

This [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=165f88eee01c2afe489d4907656923ff&version=stable) demonstrates this:

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&self) { println!("Foo"); }
}

let f = &&Foo;

// prints "foo"
f.foo();
```

By the way,

```
hs.insert((*d).to_string());
```

will also [work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=164affeff79e892e7961ea01542e46c9&version=stable), since it's first deref'd to `&str`.

Comment: The comment from @SebastianRedl and the last line from your answer drove it home for me. Deref coercion takes a bit of time getting used to... Thank you!